# difference between the root, lemma and stem for a derived word

Tags: terminology, roots, derivation, lemmas

I am a bit confused with the usage of the terms root, lemma and stem. My understanding of the terms are as follows.

- **Root**:The central (free) morpheme which has the content to which other bound morphemes are added so as to form a word.
- **Lemma**: An inflected form that acts as a head. It represents all the inflected word forms of a given root, when used independently like in a dictionary.
- **Stem**: The portion of strings that are common in all the inflections of a word.

I am further confused, when it comes to the derived words. For example, if I am dealing with the inflection 'drivers'. What is the lemma of the word, and what is the `root' of the word?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

For your English example *drivers*

- The **lemma** is *driver*
- The **stem** is also *driver*
- The **root** is *driv*

The whole thing is better explained in a language with more inflections, where things become interesting.

Take the Latin verb *laudare* "to praise"

- The **lemma** is (depending on convention) either *laudare* or *laudo* "I praise"
- There are three **stems**: The present stem *lauda*, the perfect stem *laudav*, and the supine stem *laudat* represented by the **principal parts** *laudare, laudo, laudavi, laudatum*
- The **root** is just *laud* without the so-called **thematic vowel** *a*
- The noun *laus, laudis* "praise" has root and stem *laud*

Note that the term root is language dependent, for Semitic languages it usually consists of three consonant without any vowels. Also for stems there is some leeway in the definition. Both root and stem are product of the analysis of word forms, and often there is a canonical way of doing this, but sometimes linguists may disagree.

Comment: The terms that are mentioned in this answer are extremely unconventional and I would even say some are not idiomatic in Anglo-American linguistics. Even though lemma is totally legitimate,   lemma in the sense of "lexeme" is used primarily in computational morphology and lexicography. "Theme vowel", on the other hand, is virtually non-existent in Anglo-American linguistics; the usual term is **a thematic vowel**.

Comment: @AlexB. Fixed that. I often translate terminology from my native language and look up whether the translated term exists somewhere.

Comment: @AlexB. And for lemma, I am indeed doing some corpus linguistics, it is a bread-and-butter term for me.